# UIView as popup landscape autolayout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have created a simple popup but issue is when i m trying to landscape that popup then it not working properly

NOTE : i am using Autolayout

Here's my code

```
mpop = [[MPopUp alloc] init];
mpop.frame = CGRectMake(((self.view.frame.size.width) -
                         mpop.frame.size.width) / 2,
                        ((self.view.frame.size.height) -
                         mpop.frame.size.height) / 2,
                        mpop.frame.size.width,
                        mpop.frame.size.height);

UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                           0,
                                                           self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                           self.view.frame.size.height)];

mpop.overlay = newView;

UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
visualEffectView.alpha = 0.4;
visualEffectView.frame = newView.bounds;
[newView addSubview:visualEffectView];

newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


[self.view addSubview:newView];
[mpop showInView:self.view animated:YES];
```

It working fine in Portrait mode but not working in landscape can anyone help me out?

Comment: as you are not adding any auto layout constraints to the elements when you are creating them at runtime you should use newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; instead what you used

Comment: i tried in to YES but not working i know i need to set constrain programmatically but i don't no about programmatically constrain how can i set ? @M.K.

Comment: posting answer with auto layout constraints programmatically. i will add code according to you, tell me the size of the popup you want in any mode.

Comment: i need 290 * 250 in this size in portrait and propositionally in landscape

Comment: proportionally means size will be dynamic but irrespective to rotation right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123205/discussion-between-mayank-patel-and-m-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add auto layout constraints for this situation. I have added code to your sample and posed on GitHub for your reference. find it in the below link. I had to add code in 2 files, in the view controller.m file and view.m file.

https://github.com/mahesh-agrawal/Autolayout-Popup

Check by running it. If you want to make the width or height dynamic you can replace hard coded value with a calculation like below.

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * (290.0/320.0)` instead of 290.0

Comment: perfact, Thank you :)